# Problem setting uint value to zero

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, mapping, struct

I made a little smart contracts with solidity browser,
This is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Test {
    struct User {
        string name;
        string surname;
        uint active;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => User) public userRegister;

    function add_user(string _name, string _surname) {
        bytes32 _hc=sha3(_name, _surname);
        User p = userRegister[_hc];  

        p.name=_name;
        p.surname=_surname;
        p.active=1;
    }

    function remove(string _name, string _surname)  {
        bytes32 _hc=sha3(_name, _surname);
        userRegister[_hc].active=0;  
    }

    function active(string _name, string _surname)  {
        bytes32 _hc=sha3(_name, _surname);
        userRegister[_hc].active=1;  
    }
}
```

When I use "JavaScript VM" everything's fine, but when I compile the contract with Injected Web3 there is a problem.

Adding a user (with add_user) it's all okay, but when i try to remove a user, i get an error:
callback contain no result Error: Out of gas

After some test i supposed that error is given when I try to set a uint value to zero.

Then I try to change the 0 in

```
userRegister[_hc].active=0;
```

with 9(or other int number)

```
userRegister[_hc].active=9;
```

And all works fine.

So, someone can tell me what's wrong with set a uint value to 0? And how i can re-set a uint variable to zero?
Thanks

Comment: I've tested out your code and it's an interesting problem!

Comment: try to set uint to uint256

Comment: @BadrBellaj - setting uint to uint256 did not work.

Comment: I've try to set "active" as a bool variable, then on function "add_user" i've set

    userRegister[_hc].active=true;

And in function remove, i've set

    userRegister[_hc].active=false;

But when i call remove it get the same problem..

Comment: Some discussion of this issue on https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/5m6j1q/heres_an_interesting_solidity_problem_ese_problem/

Comment: i have the same problem, i think the reason is when a uint set to 0, it take some extract move to optimise the storage of this uint(just like delete), then it will take some more gas, how ever the estimateGas function couldn't calculate it. if you raise the gas then everything's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Summary

This somehow seems to be a problem with Browser Solidity interacting with `geth`. When I deploy the contract and execute the transactions directly in `geth`, the contract works as expected.

`@PietroR91`, please submit your code as an issue in the Browser Solidity github. If you are unable to do so, I can do it later.

---

### Details

#### Environment

The error in Browser Solidity has been verified with the pragma and compiler being `^0.4.0`, `^0.4.4` and `^0.4.7`.

The `geth` environment I am using is version 1.5.5-stable on OS/X.

#### Modified Source Code

Here is your source code, modified by the addition of `getUser(...)` to check the values of the data in the mapping, and some minor formatting changes:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Test {
    struct User {
        string name;
        string surname;
        uint active;
    }

    mapping (bytes32 => User) public userRegister;

    function add_user(string _name, string _surname) {
        bytes32 _hc = sha3(_name, _surname);
        User p = userRegister[_hc];
        p.name = _name;
        p.surname = _surname;
        p.active = 1;
    }

    function remove(string _name, string _surname)  {
        bytes32 _hc = sha3(_name, _surname);
        userRegister[_hc].active = 0;
    }

    function active(string _name, string _surname)  {
        bytes32 _hc=sha3(_name, _surname);
        userRegister[_hc].active = 1;
    }

    function getUser(string _name, string _surname) constant
      returns (string name, string surname, uint256 active) {
        bytes32 _hc = sha3(_name, _surname);
        name = userRegister[_hc].name;
        surname = userRegister[_hc].surname;
        active = userRegister[_hc].active;
    }
}
```

#### Browser Solidity - Deploy And Execute `add_user(...)`

[image]

#### Browser Solidity - Attempt To Execute `remove(...)`

When attempting to execute `remove(...)` in Browser Solidity, the message `callback contain no result Error: Intrinsic gas too low` is displayed.

[image]

#### Browser Solidity - Web3 Deploy

Following is the Web3 Deploy code from Browser Solidity:

```
var testContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"userRegister","outputs":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"surname","type":"string"},{"name":"active","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_name","type":"string"},{"name":"_surname","type":"string"}],"name":"add_user","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_name","type":"string"},{"name":"_surname","type":"string"}],"name":"remove","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_name","type":"string"},{"name":"_surname","type":"string"}],"name":"getUser","outputs":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"surname","type":"string"},{"name":"active","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_name","type":"string"},{"name":"_surname","type":"string"}],"name":"active","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]);
var test = testContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

#### Deploying The Contract In `geth`

I paste the Web3 Deploy code from the previous section into my Dev `geth` console:

```
I0106 08:17:04.067480 internal/ethapi/api.go:1045] Tx(0x2ce868c7e3377f4330ef847747b471c5ff27384b67e973fff2c86f3547316db6) created: 0x22718021ba1f0ce28931c3d0653f624c6b409763
null [object Object]
undefined
...
null [object Object]
Contract mined! address: 0x22718021ba1f0ce28931c3d0653f624c6b409763 transactionHash: 0x2ce868c7e3377f4330ef847747b471c5ff27384b67e973fff2c86f3547316db6
```

#### Executing The Functions In `geth`

I then executed the following functions in `geth`:

```
> test.add_user("test_name", "test_surname", {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 400000});
I0106 08:19:07.999559 internal/ethapi/api.go:1047] Tx(0xda430dd968ce3537ed29b4e57ff6f10a4feb6fb674ac1f50ac5684368b9415c1) to: 0x22718021ba1f0ce28931c3d0653f624c6b409763
"0xda430dd968ce3537ed29b4e57ff6f10a4feb6fb674ac1f50ac5684368b9415c1"
...
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xda430dd968ce3537ed29b4e57ff6f10a4feb6fb674ac1f50ac5684368b9415c1")
{
  blockHash: "0x02e8f2b1385bafb4336a8057640967763e05ad430c47a169ce0512f5e3bc9859",
  blockNumber: 5878,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 85340,
  from: "0x000d1009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e",
  gasUsed: 85340,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0x28b34cf11c24cc9dc72ea47539b556ce8266fa5d4bed8910da24783019e6f9cb",
  to: "0x22718021ba1f0ce28931c3d0653f624c6b409763",
  transactionHash: "0xda430dd968ce3537ed29b4e57ff6f10a4feb6fb674ac1f50ac5684368b9415c1",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Checking the function got executed correctly:

```
> test.getUser("test_name", "test_surname");
["test_name", "test_surname", 1]
```

Let's now execute the `remove(...)` function with the problem:

```
> test.remove("test_name", "test_surname", {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 400000});
I0106 08:22:30.226885 internal/ethapi/api.go:1047] Tx(0x684c27aac5ff70c97c374646de9ec376ad2a2b67c7e0205445ed208b1b95b30b) to: 0x22718021ba1f0ce28931c3d0653f624c6b409763
"0x684c27aac5ff70c97c374646de9ec376ad2a2b67c7e0205445ed208b1b95b30b"
...
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x684c27aac5ff70c97c374646de9ec376ad2a2b67c7e0205445ed208b1b95b30b")
{
  blockHash: "0x895f68c8d0aa3adf2ec86e22ddc4f7ca9b185252258374430ff96988646ae7a0",
  blockNumber: 5899,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 14828,
  from: "0x000d1009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e",
  gasUsed: 14828,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0x4f21b21ed39fc110bc8c2e9e5ac3be3576c1733c59660f728bd180273dd16210",
  to: "0x22718021ba1f0ce28931c3d0653f624c6b409763",
  transactionHash: "0x684c27aac5ff70c97c374646de9ec376ad2a2b67c7e0205445ed208b1b95b30b",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Checking the function got executed correctly:

```
> test.getUser("test_name", "test_surname");
["test_name", "test_surname", 0]
```

---

### An Interesting Observations

If I modify `remove(...)` to add the following:

```
function remove(string _name, string _surname)  {
    bytes32 _hc = sha3(_name, _surname);
    userRegister[_hc].name = _name;
    userRegister[_hc].surname = _surname;
    userRegister[_hc].active = 0;
}
```

I am able to execute the function in Browser Solidity, but the returned from `getUser(...)` shows that the value of active is not modified from 1 to 0.

#### Executing The Modified `remove(...)` function in Browser Solidity

The following screen shows the `remove(...)` function being successfully executed in Browser Solidity:

[image]

Following is the transaction receipt in `geth`:

```
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x59734b415f6e1094f57b07579cfaba53325321f1cee9512c84c4b257ed222d3c")
{
  blockHash: "0x91949c01a0bf15a8d8cf558b9e9afcda686855669960c5aaf46069d9d75d5c82",
  blockNumber: 5949,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 85468,
  from: "0x000d1009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e",
  gasUsed: 85468,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0x2bf9db658636a8de8af1d4f171c8b8ea97d11bf55592d0fce67b69f3947719a6",
  to: "0x49472fa49f6e3e84c0c038416f000eaeddb5c891",
  transactionHash: "0x59734b415f6e1094f57b07579cfaba53325321f1cee9512c84c4b257ed222d3c",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

The following screen shows the second invocation of `getUser(...)` where the results are unchanged. `active` is still `1` instead of the expected `0`:

[image]